# Querying data from Oracle database using java servlet with Netbeans

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, servlets

From index.jsp code,

```
statement.executeQuery("select * from fus where tester_num like 'hf60' ") ;
```

Example I want "hf60" to be a variable(userinput), wherein USER must input/write  data from input text then submit and get the data so that the result will be

```
("select  * from fus where tester_num like 'userinput' ")
```

Where should I insert that code, Is it in InsertServlet .java or in Index.jsp.? or make another filename.java code? Please help. Thanks;)

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>SHIFT REPORT </TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR=##342D7E>
    <CENTER>
    <H2><FONT COLOR="#ECD672" FACE="Verdana" >SHIFT REPORT</FONT></H2></CENTER>
<hr>
    <% 


 Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oradev2.*****.com:1521:RPADB","shift_admin",  //
         "shift_admin"
            );

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
//**Should I input the codes here?**
        ResultSet resultset = 
            statement.executeQuery("select  * from fus where tester_num like 'hf60") ; 
    %>

    <TABLE BORDER="1" BGCOLOR="CCFFFF" width='200%' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'   bordercolor="black" border='1'>
        <TR>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'> <font size='2'>RECORD NUMBER</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>TESTER NUMBER</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>DATE</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>TIME</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>SYSTEM TYPE</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>PACKAGE</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>SOCKETS</TH>
            <TH bgcolor='#DAA520'><font size='2'>VALIDATED BY</TH>
        </TR>

        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <TR>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getLong(1) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(2) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getDate(3) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(4) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(5) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(6) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(7) %></center></TD>
            <TD> <font size='2'><center><%= resultset.getString(8) %></center></TD>
            </TR>

        <% } %>

    </TABLE>     
        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**InsertServlet.java**

```
package fusion.shift.servlets.db;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class InsertServlet extends HttpServlet {


public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { 
    super.init(config); 
} 

public void destroy() { 
} 
public boolean processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException, IOException{


            String rec_num = request.getParameter("rec_num");
            String tester_num = request.getParameter("tester_num");
            String t_date = request.getParameter("t_date");
            String t_time = request.getParameter("t_time");
            String sys_type = request.getParameter("sys_type");
            String packages = request.getParameter("package");
            String sockets = request.getParameter("sockets");
            String sockets = request.getParameter("val");


    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oradev2.*****.com:1521:RPADB","shift_admin",  //
         "shift_admin"
            );


        String sql;
                    sql = "INSERT INTO fusion_shiftrpt(RECORD_NUM, TESTER_NUM, T_DATE, T_TIME, SYSTEM_TYPE, PACKAGE, SOCKETS,VAL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt = con.createStatement();

               ps.setString(1, rec_num);
             .0+  ps.setString(2, tester_num);
                             ps.setString(3, t_date);
                             ps.setString(4, t_time);
                             ps.setString(5, sys_type);
                             ps.setString(6, packages);
                             ps.setString(7, sockets);
                             ps.setString(8, val);
                             ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if(ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if(con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

 return(true);
 }


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request,response);     

}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
 processRequest(request,response);
 //String url = request.getRequestURI();
 //System.out.println(url);

}
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

***If*** you insist on staying with this design, I would suggest that you use [JSTL](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/standard-doc/intro.html). This provides a set of tags for accessing data, controlling logic, and performing SQL access.

See the Sun Tutorial on the Standard Tag Library and the [SQL tags](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnald.html). This is a much better approach than embedding scriptlets into your JSP. That said, I would recommend this approach (or scriplets) only be used for prototypes or as a very-temporary fix.

With JSTL, you could replace all of the scriptlets with something similar to:

```
<sql:query var="rows" >
    select  * from fus where tester_num like ?
    <sql:param value="${param.user_input}" />
</sql:query>

<table>
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}">
      <tr>
         <td>${row.column1name}</td>
         <td>${row.column2name}</td>
         <td>${row.column3name}</td>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have access to the request in a `JSP`. So if your `JSP` were to be accessed like this:

```
test.jsp?q=userinput
```

You could get to it like this in the `JSP`:

```
request.getParameter('userinput');
```

You should convert your `JSP` code to at least use a `preparedStatement` when you do this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from fus where tester_num like ?");
ps.setString(1, "%" + request.getParameter('userinput') + "%");
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Maybe slap a caveat on this answer that this is not a recommended best practice...

Comment: @JamesSchek What practice IS the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

As tvanfosson said, you should remove all database access code from your view logic (JSP). You should just show the info in your JSP, let the Servlet do all the processing. I also strongly recommend you to use an OMR framework like Hibernate.